# How to pronounce $\chi^2$?

Tags: statistics, pronunciation

When talking about the $\chi^2$-test or the $\chi^2$-distribution, my colleagues have different pronunciations of the letter $\chi$. How should it be pronounced?

I quickly found three different ways:

Kai-sound like in "kite": http://youtu.be/5_74FkJXG68?t=4s

Ch-sound like in "Loch Ness": http://youtu.be/EijkVbkPXT8?t=10m24s

He-sound like in "he": http://youtu.be/28yu1PFc438?t=3m45s

Comment: This isn't a question about mathematics.

Comment: What is mathematics?

Comment: [A good start.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics) This is more a question about the English language, or the Greek language, than about mathematics.

Comment: "Kaaee Squared"

Comment: Funny thing is the greek pronounciation is closer to "Ch" than to "Kai"...

Comment: @Najib-Idrissi When you start learning mathematics, you need to learn a word for + and every mathematical symbol you use. If not, you cannot even talk about mathematics. So yes, I would claim that this question is very much about mathematics.

Comment: The greek pronunciation is similar the the german in `ich`; with the international phonetic alphabet: `[çi]`

Comment: @JosteinTrondal Good question. This should be paid attention to in math teaching. My high school teachers and college professors also have various pronunciations of Greek letters. And often that would give rise to a lot of confusion among students, esp those who didn't know anything about Greek beforehand. BTW, the various writing versions of Greek letters by teachers are also interesting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_%28letter%29):

> Chi (uppercase Χ, lowercase χ; Greek: χῖ) is the 22nd letter of the Greek alphabet, **pronounced /ˈkaɪ/ or /ˈkiː/ in English.**

So "kite"-like /ˈkaɪ/ is okay.
The traditional greek pronounciation is more like /ˈxiː/, so this is the origin of the "loch"-like pronounciation and the "he" in the linked YT video.

Note that this question is better suited for [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), since it's about language and not about Mathematics.

Comment: In fact **['xi:]** (or in informal notation \khee\ ) is also correct, though some will find it a trifle pedantic. It is not wrong to use a (classical) Greek pronunciation in English.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you have any references for that? If so, feel free to include them in my answer. Your pronounciation reminds me of $\xi$.

Comment: It’s too obvious to require a reference. The Wikipedia article is merely describing the usual English pronunciations; there is no implication that the classical Greek pronunciation is incorrect when used in English. Similarly, it is not wrong to to pronounce Erdős’s name in the Hungarian fashion. **['ksi:]** and **[xi:]** are quite different; confusing them would be like confusing *tsar* and *Shar* (pet form of *Charlene*).

Comment: I wasn't able to locate a greek pronounciation table ;) If [xi:] is like _Charlene_ then that's actually what I pronounce $\chi$ as, but I must admit I'm not an expert in IPA.

Comment: No, it’s not; IPA [x] is the sound of *ch* in German *Bach* and Scottish *loch*. I was simply giving an analogy of sounds — *ts* and *sh* — whose difference is comparable to that between IPA [ks], the initial sound of the Greek name of ξ, and IPA [x], the initial sound of the Greek name of χ.

Comment: @alexr I disagree that this question is not about mathematics. It is as important to know how to pronounce a mathematical symbol as it is to know how to write it.

Comment: @JosteinTrondal Albeit necessary, the _topic_ is still language. You wouldn't ask how to pronounce the letter A on this site either.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm from germany so describing my pronounciation with german words, it'd be like _Ich_, just reversed.

Comment: @AlexR: Not quite: it’s the ach-Laut, not the ich-Laut.

Comment: @AlexR: The question is about how to pronounce $\chi^2$ in statistics. The letter $\chi$ itself evidently has different pronunciations, but perhaps in statistics there is (or should be) a certain way that mathematicians agree upon, maybe based on tradition. So I would probably not get a good answer in a language forum.

Comment: @JosteinTrondal As has been pointed out, your argument is invalid because $\chi^2$ is pronounced as _$\chi$ squared_ with the regular _language-specific_ pronounciation of $\chi$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No, **my** pronounciation is (...). You'll get a dry throat reading out "Ach" a few times, so I'll stick with the softer Ich. :P

Comment: @AlexR: Sorry: I missed the *my* in your earlier comment and was describing IPA [x].

Comment: @AlexR: The pronunciation of $\chi$ is context sensitive, and the context here is statistics. And I know that it is being pronounced more than one way in statistics. But my question is not how it could be pronounced, but how it should be pronounced. I do not, however, hope to get a definitive answer to this question, but it is interesting to have a discussion about it.

Comment: @JosteinTrondal I fail to see what should be special about $\chi$ in a mathematical context as opposed to regular language, as the pronounciations **are not context-sensitive** in this case, I assure you.

Comment: @AlexR I don't think there is any reason for being anything special in itself about $\chi$ in a mathematical context as opposed to regular language. But tradition in statistics might favor one particular pronunciation. I don't know if this is the case, and I don't think anyone knows.